# How can I render html code in a div using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to render some HTML on the fly in my website without success. I've tried using jQuery's .html() function as below:

**My html**

```
<div id='open_ender_output'></div>
```

**My JQuery**

```
var openEnderContent = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color: #ff0000;"&gt;DDD&lt;/span&gt;!!!!!&lt;strong&gt;666666666666&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
//openEnderContent comes from my backend
$('#open_ender_output').html(openEnderContent)
```

**The result is**

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">DDD</span>!!!!!<strong>666666666666</strong></p>
```

Is there a way to make the browser render that result on the fly so it  reflects the specific styles set on the text?

Comment: You are missing a single quote on your last jQuery line

Comment: Thanks elementzero, I've corrected the error now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Decode the content by creating a temporary element.

```js
var openEnderContent = '&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color: #ff0000;"&gt;DDD&lt;/span&gt;!!!!!&lt;strong&gt;666666666666&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';

$('#open_ender_output').html(
  // create an element where the html content as the string
  $('<div/>', {
    html: openEnderContent
  // get text content from element for decoded text  
  }).text()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='open_ender_output'></div>
```

---

Or you need to use a string which contains unescaped symbols.

```js
var openEnderContent = '<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">DDD</span>!!!!!<strong>666666666666</strong></p>';

$('#open_ender_output').append(openEnderContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='open_ender_output'></div>
```

Comment: Pranav Thanks! This works fantastic. Although not quite sure why this works. If you have a couple of spare minutes could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Andrew :  where `&lt;` stands for `<` which is using to escape the symbol .... to define as an html tag you should use `<p>` instead of `&lt;p&gt;`

Comment: @Andrew :  actually what I'm doing in the code is , 1. creating an element with the given string as html content 2. getting the text content from the created element wich is the decoded text... 3. setting the fetched text as html content

Comment: Thanks a lot Pranav. Now it's quite clear to me the issue and the solution. Sounds so simple in hindsight!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. You need to differentiate between single and double quotes when creating a string. You're closing your string by adding double quotes inside double quotes.

Use the var below.

```
var openEnderContent = "<span style='color: #ff0000;'>DDD</span>!!!!!<strong>666666666666</strong></p>";
$('#open_ender_output').html(openEnderContent);
```

Fiddle for example: https://jsfiddle.net/acr2xg6u/

Comment: I see Gezzasa for sure an issue with the quotes. However, that's exactly the output I get from the backend so I was looking for a solution that works directly with the original string. Pranav approach bellow did work well. THanks

Comment: @Andrew glad his solution worked for you. His string starts with double quotes though where yours starts with single, if that is the exact string that you're receiving from the back end.

Comment: Gezzasa I'm getting so confused with the symbols right now. Sorry just a Newbie here. I see what you mean! You are right as well, changing the outer single quotes to double quotes and the inner one to single ones resolves the issue. Thanks for pointing this out again!

Comment: @Andrew not a problem. You'll learn something new every day while developing. It's as much exciting as it is infuriating. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery to

```
var openEnderContent = '<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">DDD</span>!!!!!<strong>666666666666</strong></p>';

$('#open_ender_output').append(openEnderContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing problem from what I can tell.

```
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="color: #ff0000;"&gt;DDD&lt;/span&gt;!!!!!&lt;strong&gt;666666666666&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```

You cannot create strings like that. If you are inside one, you must use the other:

```
"My name is 'Josh Crowe'"
'My name is "Josh Crowe"'
```

Here's corrected code:

```
"&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style='color: #ff0000;'&gt;DDD&lt;/span&gt;!!!!!&lt;strong&gt;666666666666&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"
```